# How Do I Update the Status of Service in the Windows Dialog

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

How do I update the `Status` column in the Windows Services Dialog?

- When the services goes into a (managed) Fault-State...I want to update the dialog

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but no one has answered this...

Unfortunately, as it turns-out, you cannot directly update the `Status` field, as it is READ-ONLY.  However, you can PAUSE the service, like so:

```
var serviceController = new ServiceController(ServiceName);
serviceController.Pause();      // Pauses the service
serviceController.Refresh();    // Refreshes the Dialog UI with the new Status
```

This is unfortunate, as there is no "real" way to show a FAULT-STATE for the service.